# obstacle avoidance implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab, robotics

This could be a really broad question, but if you can help me with ideas, it would be a great help to me.

I am trying to implement basic path finding algorithm in matlab. I have to create a map where the robot can navigate and also avoid obstacles and reach destination. I have the algorithm fine with me. But am struggling with the gui as I haven't used much of Gui in matlab.

This is the following idea I had.

I created a plot and just defined 4 coods for each obstacle, destination as a circle and a start point. But am stuck when I think how I can detect whether the robot has hit an obstacle or not. One way is to create the equation of line and try to see if the point ever comes to lie on it. But the movement is based ona  random generated variable. Thus it is possible for the robot to cross the line and get inside the polygon.

My apologies for bein too elaborate, but can you please tell me the best way to implement this in matlab? It is mandatory to do this in matlab. Please suggest me a better and easy way to program it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If your obstacles are all polygons you could try to use the ray casting algorithm described on the following wikipedia site.

[Point in polygon algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

With this you should be able to determine if the robot position lies within an obstacle, or you could determine if the next movement will bring the robot into contact with the obstacle.

If you are looking for a simple algorithm that can take care of obstacles inherently i would suggest the potential fields algorithm (can get stuck in certain cases)

[Potential Fields](https://web.archive.org/web/20190725152740/http://aigamedev.com:80/open/tutorials/potential-fields/)

else you can also try the A* algorithm, which is better in my opinion; [Good description of A*](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)